# How to make bootable USB for Ubuntu in Windows 7?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I downloaded the Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.2 from [this webpage](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

But when I am running it, the <kbd>Create</kbd> icon is not working and I am unable to figure out what the problem is? I even formatted the pendrive (8GB) but the result was same.

Comment: try unetbootin.And make sure that your usb is formatted into fat32 filesytem.After formatting,unplug and plug the usb drive again.Then open unetbootin,it will automatically detect your usb.

Answer (score 3):

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.

[Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did all this stuff for several times but the result was same. I downloaded the same file that you mentioned. Please , give me an another solution.

Comment: Are you running only windows or do you have a firend with a ubuntu distro?

Comment: alternatively you can use the [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)